# R: how to plot ROC for logistic regression model whit missing values

Tags: r, logistic-regression, missing-data, roc, proc-r-package

I have a logistic regression model and I'd like to plot ROC curve. All variables have some missing data. Here's the summary:

```r
X<-cbind(outcome, var1, var2)
summary(X)
#    outcome            var1             var2      
# Min.   :0.0000   Min.   : 0.100   Min.   : 65.1  
# 1st Qu.:0.0000   1st Qu.: 0.600   1st Qu.: 91.9  
# Median :0.0000   Median : 1.000   Median :101.0  
# Mean   :0.2643   Mean   : 2.421   Mean   :110.3  
# 3rd Qu.:1.0000   3rd Qu.: 2.200   3rd Qu.:114.5  
# Max.   :1.0000   Max.   :34.800   Max.   :388.4  
# NA's   :165      NA's   :80       NA's   :30
```

The model seems to work:

```r
model <- glm(outcome~var1+var2,family=binomial)
summary(model)
# Call:
# glm(formula = outcome ~ var1 + var2, family = binomial)
# 
# Deviance Residuals: 
#      Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max  
# -1.63470  -0.67079  -0.56255   0.01727   2.07577  
# 
# Coefficients:
#              Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
# (Intercept) -3.652208   0.973013  -3.754 0.000174 ***
# var1         0.386811   0.147054   2.630 0.008528 ** 
# var2         0.016165   0.008075   2.002 0.045316 *  
# ---
# Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
# 
# (Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)
# 
#     Null deviance: 135.91  on 117  degrees of freedom
# Residual deviance: 108.84  on 115  degrees of freedom
#   (187 observations deleted due to missingness)
# AIC: 114.84
# 
# Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 6
```

But when I try to calcutate ROC curve, there is an error:

```r
library(pROC)
roc(model)
# Error in roc.default(model) : No valid data provided.
```

I thought it could be due to missing data and I tried to add na.action = na.exclude option, but the problem still persist:

```r
model2 <- glm(outcome~var1+var2,family=binomial, na.action = na.exclude)
roc(model2)
# Error in roc.default(model2) : No valid data provided.
```

I also tried with lrm instead of glm, but still doesn't work:

```r
model.lrm<-lrm(outcome~var1+var2, options(na.action="na.delete"), x=TRUE, y=TRUE)
model.lrm
# Frequencies of Missing Values Due to Each Variable
# outcome    var1    var2 
#     165      80      30 
# 
# Logistic Regression Model
#  
#  lrm(formula = outcome ~ var1 + var2, data = options(na.action = "na.delete"), 
#      x = TRUE, y = TRUE)
#  
#  
#                         Model Likelihood    Discrimination    Rank Discrim.    
#                               Ratio Test           Indexes          Indexes    
#  Obs           118    LR chi2      27.07    R2       0.300    C       0.782    
#   0             87    d.f.             2    g        1.377    Dxy     0.565    
#   1             31    Pr(> chi2) <0.0001    gr       3.964    gamma   0.565    
#  max |deriv| 7e-05                          gp       0.189    tau-a   0.221    
#                                             Brier    0.150                     
 
#            Coef    S.E.   Wald Z Pr(>|Z|)
#  Intercept -3.6522 0.9730 -3.75  0.0002  
#  var1       0.3868 0.1471  2.63  0.0085  
#  var2       0.0162 0.0081  2.00  0.0453  
#  
roc(model.lrm)
# Error in roc.default(model.lrm) : No valid data provided.
```

Here are first 20 observations:

```
> dput(head (dati[, c(2,3,4)], 20))
structure(list(outcome = c(NA, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, NA, 0), var1 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.3, 0.5, 1.5, 4.5, 2, 2.2, 0.7, NA, NA, 0.3), 
    var2 = c(117, 84, NA, 90, 91, 113, 88, NA, 108, 178, 100, 
    86, 86, 95, 92, 111, 103, 81, NA, 95)), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

What is  the problem?

Comment: This can be solved easily in 'riskRegression'. If you provide a data sample, I can show you. 'dput(data)'

Comment: Which package is `roc` from? Surely you need to provide data to the roc function to calculate predictions from which you can estimate true and false positive rates

Comment: @alan ocallaghan `roc` is from pROC package

Comment: If you consult the help for the `roc` function, you'll see that this function needs a certain input. None of it seems to be a model object. So you need to provide the input in the format the function requires.

Comment: @deschen maybe `roc` is not the function that I need. So how can I plot a ROC curve from a multivariate logistic regression model with missing data both in outcome and predictors?

Comment: Missing data is not your problem. Your model will only take into account non-missing cases anyway. Your problem is a lakc of understanding what input the `roc` function needs. (see the comment from @alanocallaghan in your answer below).

Answer (score 1):

A ROC curve isn't built on a model, but on predictions derived from the model. Therefore you need to use the [`predict`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/predict.glm.html) function to obtain predictions on the data. It looks like this:

```
predictions <- predict(model)
```

And then you can call the `roc` function with those:

```
roc(outcome, predictions)
```

The missing values will be ignored automatically.

This makes it easy and very similar if you are using a test set:

```
test_predictions <- predict(model, newdata = test_data)
roc(test_data$outcome, test_predictions)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution modifying the code as follow:

```
roc(outcome, as.vector(fitted.values(model)),plot=TRUE)
```

Comment: Plotting an ROC plot using the data used to create the model is not meaningful

Comment: I was only trying to do with R what I usually do with SAS by using 'outroc=' option in proc logistic